# What is loading a certain Module? (ActiveResource)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Short Version:  **How to determine which file or gem is requiring a certain file**

A bit longer ..

I have a Rails 3.0.3 / mongoid application, so I am not using ActiveRecord.  The top of my application.rb file looks like so:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

#require 'rails/all'
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
```

But after rails loads, if I go into the console and type:

```
defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
#=> "constant"
```

I expected it to be `nil`.

So one of my gems must be loading ActiveRecord.

How do I determine which gem or file is requiring ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way to do it, but not sure its the best:

Since I am using bundler, I simply added a break point after bundler requires the file, and then check afterwards if the file was loaded.

I added the breakpoint in `Bundler::Runtime#require` at the `Kernel.require` line.

Chime in if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your `Gemfile.lock`, you can figure out which of your gems has ActiveRecord as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks -- having a dependency isn't enough.  A bunch of gems have dependencies for their test suites, but do not load them when required for standard use.  And on the flip side, some times the dependency is not stated, and they still require the file

Comment: Though I should add, this should be the first place you should look -- it often will help you

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think test dependencies for your gems would appear in `Gemfile.lock` (otherwise every gem would depend on rspec or test-unit). And while it's *possible* for a gem to require a file from a gem it doesn't specify as a dependency, it's *horrible* practice.